# How can I avoid manual scrolling through long output of a Vim script to automate execution of the script?

Tags: shell, vim

I want to automate the install of Conque GDB from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4582.

So I wrote these two commands.

```
wget "http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=22163" -O conque_gdb.vmb
vim +"so % | q" conque_gdb.vmb
```

The first command downloads conbque_gdb.vmb. The second command executes the two commands the author recommends in the above link, i.e. execute `:so %` and `:q`.

However, there is one problem. The output due to executing `so %` is huge and it causes the Vim window to display a huge output with `-- More --` in the end that I must scroll through by pressing Enter, before Vim can execute the `q` command and quit.

```
"conque_gdb.vmb" 8489L, 292519C
Vimball Archive
extracted <autoload/conque_gdb.vim>: 561 lines
wrote /root/.vim/autoload/conque_gdb.vim
extracted <autoload/conque_term.vim>: 1674 lines
wrote /root/.vim/autoload/conque_term.vim
extracted <autoload/conque_gdb/conque_gdb.py>: 294 lines
wrote /root/.vim/autoload/conque_gdb/conque_gdb.py
extracted <autoload/conque_gdb/conque_gdb_gdb.py>: 17 lines
wrote /root/.vim/autoload/conque_gdb/conque_gdb_gdb.py
extracted <autoload/conque_gdb/conque_sole_gdb.py>: 82 lines
wrote /root/.vim/autoload/conque_gdb/conque_sole_gdb.py
extracted <autoload/conque_gdb/gdbinit_confirm.gdb>: 24 lines
wrote /root/.vim/autoload/conque_gdb/gdbinit_confirm.gdb
extracted <autoload/conque_gdb/gdbinit_no_confirm.gdb>: 20 lines
wrote /root/.vim/autoload/conque_gdb/gdbinit_no_confirm.gdb
extracted <autoload/conque_gdb/conque_gdb.gdb>: 12 lines
wrote /root/.vim/autoload/conque_gdb/conque_gdb.gdb
extracted <autoload/conque_term/conque.py>: 1176 lines
wrote /root/.vim/autoload/conque_term/conque.py
extracted <autoload/conque_term/conque_globals.py>: 317 lines
wrote /root/.vim/autoload/conque_term/conque_globals.py
extracted <autoload/conque_term/conque_screen.py>: 236 lines
-- More --
```

Can I somehow avoid this scrolling in between and install Conque GDB in a fully automated fashion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `silent` command to suppress output.

```
vim +"silent so % | q" conque_gdb.vmb
```

Read `:h silent`